# The lambda function, after an api call, doesn't return the result to my main script

Tags: javascript, lambda, netlify

I made a web app that uses an API.
For hides the key of the API and host it on netlify I've used a lambda function:

```js
exports.handler = async event => {

  const apiKey =  process.env.apiKey
  
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.waqi.info/feed/${cityName}/?token=${apiKey}`)
  const result = await response.json() 

  const pass = (body) => {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }
  }

  return pass(result)
}
```

that makes the call to the API and share the result of the call to my main script, that one elaborates this response.

```js
async function checkAir() {
    
let cityName = document.getElementById("cityName").value;

// Call API
const response = await fetch("../netlify/functions/lambda")
const result = await response.json()

console.log("response" + response)
console.log("result" + result)
}
```

When it runs, doesn't works, and gives the error:

```
GET 'url/.netlify/functions/lambda' 404
```

Comment: The URL is incorrect, Error 502 means bad gateway. Code might be correct but it's the path to the lambda that needs to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try using the developer tools in your Browser.
Inspect > Network Tab. and refresh your page to run the script.

Find the http request for lambda, and investigate the request, maybe the path isn't correct.